# Add kinetic sensor to turtlebot3 robot in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I`m trying to add a kinect v2 sensor model to turtlebot3 robot.

I download the kinect model from this  [repository](https://github.com/wangxian4423/kinect_v2_udrf) and it work when I launch in gazebo with the command

```
roslaunch kinect_v2 gazebo.launch
```

The turtlebot robot was installed by

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot3*
```

The simulation is loaded correctly when I launch it by the command:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch
```

The topics from the robot are correctly published

Now, I would like to add the kinect sensor model to the turtlebot3 robot.
In the folder `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot3_description/urdf`  only has .xacro files. One of then is the `turtlebot3_burguer.urdf.xacro` which I suppose to be the one to be modified.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="turtlebot3_burger" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:include filename="$(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/common_properties.xacro"/>
  <xacro:include filename="$(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_burger.gazebo.xacro"/>

  <link name="base_footprint"/>

  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_footprint"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.010" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="-0.032 0 0.0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://turtlebot3_description/meshes/bases/burger_base.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="light_black"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="-0.032 0 0.070" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.140 0.140 0.143"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="8.2573504e-01"/>
      <inertia ixx="2.2124416e-03" ixy="-1.2294101e-05" ixz="3.4938785e-05"
               iyy="2.1193702e-03" iyz="-5.0120904e-06"
               izz="2.0064271e-03" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="wheel_left_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="wheel_left_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.08 0.023" rpy="-1.57 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="wheel_left_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://turtlebot3_description/meshes/wheels/left_tire.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="dark"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.018" radius="0.033"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="2.8498940e-02" />
      <inertia ixx="1.1175580e-05" ixy="-4.2369783e-11" ixz="-5.9381719e-09"
               iyy="1.1192413e-05" iyz="-1.4400107e-11"
               izz="2.0712558e-05" />
      </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="wheel_right_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="wheel_right_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 -0.080 0.023" rpy="-1.57 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="wheel_right_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://turtlebot3_description/meshes/wheels/right_tire.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="dark"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.018" radius="0.033"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="2.8498940e-02" />
      <inertia ixx="1.1175580e-05" ixy="-4.2369783e-11" ixz="-5.9381719e-09"
               iyy="1.1192413e-05" iyz="-1.4400107e-11"
               izz="2.0712558e-05" />
      </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="caster_back_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="caster_back_link"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.081 0 -0.004" rpy="-1.57 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="caster_back_link">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0.001 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.030 0.009 0.020"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="0.005" />
      <inertia ixx="0.001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
               iyy="0.001" iyz="0.0"
               izz="0.001" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="imu_link"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.032 0 0.068" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="imu_link"/>

  <joint name="scan_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base_scan"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.032 0 0.172" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="base_scan">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://turtlebot3_description/meshes/sensors/lds.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="dark"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.015 0 -0.0065" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.0315" radius="0.055"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.114" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
      <inertia ixx="0.001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
               iyy="0.001" iyz="0.0" 
               izz="0.001" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

</robot>
```

I tried some tutorials but none of then worked for me.

I`m using:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- ROS Version: Kinetic

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342301/add-kinetic-sensor-to-turtlebot3-robot-in-gazebo/) by [ricardo.sutana](https://answers.ros.org/users/48238/ricardo.sutana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/34727/vbs/) on 2020-01-22**:
Hi Ricardo! I didn't get your problem: Are you looking for general instructions on how to update a xacro file? Or do you already know how to do it but are getting an error during the xacro parsing? (in which case what is the error?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[The URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) are really good to learn how to create or adapt urdf and xacro files (part 2 should be enough).

But your case seems simpler, as you already have both of the URDF definitions that you need. You should be able to mostly just replicate the example code given in the [kinect_v2_standalone.urdf.xacro](https://github.com/wangxian4423/kinect_v2_udrf/blob/master/kinect_v2/urdf/kinect_v2_standalong.urdf.xacro).

More specifically, you would modify the xacro file that you posted above to include:

```
<xacro:include filename="$(find kinect_v2)/urdf/kinect_v2.urdf.xacro" />

.
.
.

<xacro:kinect_v2  parent="base_link">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</xacro:kinect_v2>
```

Modifying the desired relative pose of the camera accordingly ('origin' tag above).

---

Originally posted by [vbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/34727/vbs/) with karma: 62 on 2020-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ricardo.sutana](https://answers.ros.org/users/48238/ricardo.sutana/) on 2020-01-29**:
Thank you VBS
It not worked for turtlebot3, but works perfectly for husky A200 robot which is the simulation that I really need.
I owe you a beer!

**Comment by [vbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/34727/vbs/) on 2020-01-29**:
Great, glad I could help!
PS: if you think the answer is correct, click the check button near it so others can more easily find it :)